# Showing All Errors Only (null): Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {

Tags: xcode8

I'm using xcode 8.1 . Suddenly An error occured.

I didn't understand what will have to do if any one have figured out this then

Plz Help me.

Log as following

CopySwiftLibs /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian\ Express.app
    cd "/Users/online/Documents/Indian Express"
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk
    export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 0BB37D869CBEC02B92622A237B58F54DFE00B053 --scan-executable /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian\ Express.app/Indian\ Express --scan-folder /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian\ Express.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian\ Express.app/PlugIns --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework --scan-folder /Users/online/Documents/Indian\ Express/GoogleMobileAds.framework --scan-folder /Users/online/Documents/Indian\ Express/Bolts.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework --scan-folder /Users/online/Documents/Indian\ Express/FBSDKShareKit.framework --scan-folder /Users/online/Documents/Indian\ Express/FBSDKCoreKit.framework --scan-folder /Users/online/Documents/Indian\ Express/FBSDKLoginKit.framework --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian\ Express.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian\ Express.app --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib

Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: 4
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib' '-r' '-o' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' '-r' '-o' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib'
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib' '-r' '-o' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib'
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDarwin.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDarwin.dylib' '-r' '-o' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib'
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDispatch.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDispatch.dylib' '-r' '-o' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib'
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib' '-r' '-o' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib'
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib' '-r' '-o' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib'
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib' '-r' '-o' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib'
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib' '-r' '-o' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib'
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftUIKit.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftUIKit.dylib' '-r' '-o' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib'
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib to /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  /usr/bin/codesign '-r-' '--display' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code object is not signed at all
Codesigning /Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '0BB37D869CBEC02B92622A237B58F54DFE00B053' '--verbose' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
0BB37D869CBEC02B92622A237B58F54DFE00B053: no identity found
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
    /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '0BB37D869CBEC02B92622A237B58F54DFE00B053' '--verbose' '/Users/online/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Indian_Express-elfbdjhonaqzmughbywmrbvlfces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Indian Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
}

Thanks A lot

Comment: "0BB37D869CBEC02B92622A237B58F54DFE00B053: no identity found error" -- suggests that you're missing some certificate (or maybe profile).  Has this ever built on the system you're now using?

Comment: Every thing working before but suddenly xcode throws error ,  All certificate and provising profiles are working well before but now show error of this type , i did't understand why this is happing